# pg4admin 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, pgadmin-4

I just installed the desktop version of pg4admin after having difficulty running it using my prior install.  I used the following [installing documentation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/831262/how-to-install-pgadmin-4-v1-0-in-desktop-mode-on-ubuntu-16-04/) to pull this off.

However, when I run the pgadmin4 service, the page gives my the following error:

> Unauthorized
>
> The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Also, on the terminal I'm getting the following exception:

```html
Starting pgAdmin 4. Please navigate to http://localhost:5050 in your browser.
2016-11-01 01:14:41,981: ERROR pgadmin: The desktop user pgadmin4@pgadmin.org was not found in the configuration database.
2016-11-01 01:14:42,004: ERROR pgadmin: The desktop user pgadmin4@pgadmin.org was not found in the configuration database.
2016-11-01 01:18:45,650: ERROR pgadmin: The desktop user pgadmin4@pgadmin.org was not found in the configuration database.
2016-11-01 01:18:45,664: ERROR pgadmin: The desktop user pgadmin4@pgadmin.org was not found in the configuration database.
```

Did I miss anything in the install process?  What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to fix this?  If yes, please accept the answer that helped you.

Comment: Before you take the security approaches below in an employment or home setting, think about what you're doing. Disabling browser security on a server can cause major issues. Most viruses, malware, spyware, trojans, etc... happen from browsers running in Admin mode (with an Administrator user) on Windows.  With the browser security turned off, you'll definitely run into quite a few exploits.  Try this instead.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66538220/640205

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In my case the problem is **Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration (IE ESC)** (btw my OS is Windows Server 2012 R2)

Go to `Server Manager`, choose `Local Server` from the left pane. 
On the right pane, there is "**IE Enhanced Security Configuration**", the status is "`on`".
Click on that `On`, choose `Off` (I turned off for both the *Administrators* and *Users*, I guess one of them should be enough but I was not sure which one).
Click `OK`, then click the refresh button on top (or close the server manager).
Refresh the pg admin4 page (or if that does not work, right click on pg Admin4 system tray icon, then choose "`New PgAdmin4 window`").

Comment: I additionally needed to kill all postgresql pgAdmin related processes/services (in TaskManager). Then it worked.

Comment: According to @koax26 answer, you can also white list the address instead of turning off the security https://stackoverflow.com/a/57265347/5122657

Answer (score 12):

Delete "pgadmin4.db" file & start pgAdmin4 again.

**Linux:**

~/.pgadmin/pgadmin4.db

**Windows:**

%appdata%\pgAdmin\pgadmin4.db

Note: You will lose all of your saved server listing from your previous install.

Comment: It worked! This happens when you have pgadmin3 previously installed. pgadmin4 can't digest some of the old version configuration. To run both version 3 & 4 in parallel I created "~/.pgadmin4" directory instead and pointed ver 4 to it.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I killed the pgadmin4 runtime, deleted the entire ~/.pgadmin folder and relaunched and still same problem.  I'm on Antergos and installed the pgadmin4 package, so I'm not familiar with manual desktop setup.

Answer (score 11):

@Leonard AB
Thanks for the solution. Worked for me. After confirming that was the issue rather than leave **IE Enhanced Security Configuration** off I white listed http://127.0.0.1.

Within IE:

1. Click on the Cog and the top right of the browser or go to Internet 
   Options via Control Panel
2. Click on the Security tab and select Trusted sites in the zone box and then click on the Sites button
3. Add *http://127.0.0.1* to the list and hit close, finally hit ok and confirm it works

Apologies for not adding this as a comment to your post but I don't have a high enough rep.

Comment: thanks. I linked this into the comment of my answer.

Comment: I had the same problem in a Server 2016 after installing pgadmin v4.15. This solution worked for me even in the case of using Chrome for server access

Answer (score 8):

in linux ubuntu 16.04 copy the adress in the file ~/.pgAdmin4.14570597673959349582.addr into your browser window. Looks like it contains the key.

Comment: @Jayen, it is redirecting :)

Comment: You can also use "Copy server URL" from the tray icon (pgAdmin 4)

Answer (score 8):

Following is working for me (using SolydK):

- right click on "tray icon"
- select "Configure"
- set "Browser Command" (e.g. "/usr/bin/firefox" %URL%)

Answer (score 4):

I solved by right clicking on tray icon, settings and changing the URL field to

> /usr/bin/firefox "%URL%"

Found it on
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186036/pgadmin4-401-unauthorized-in-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 1):

### **Not an answer** but a **workaround**

I solved it installing the `pgadmin4-apache2` package  and visiting the `http://localhost/pgAdmin4` URL

Answer (score 1):

Web-based Pgadmin application uses cookies to store its information.pgAdmin mainly stores 3 cookies namely

- **PGADMIN_KEY**
- **PGADMIN_LANGUAGE**
- **pga4_session**

So, to use the pgAdmin application you must have to enable your browser cookies so that these 3 cookies will stored in your browser.

In Chrome

- On your computer, open **Chrome**.
- At the top right, click More [image] and then Settings.
- At the bottom, click **Advanced**.
- Under "**Privacy and security**," click **Site settings**.
- Click **Cookies**.
- There click on "**Block**" toggle button then we will be switched to "**Allow sites to save and read cookie data.**"

[image: Change toggle from block to allow]

Then try to open pdadmin4 and you will get your pgAdmin4 home screen.

Answer (score 1):

With `pgAdmin 4 v4.28` and `Windows` a new behavior has appeared and authentification dialog never open in the browser when you load the program. To fix this change the registry key at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.js\Content Type` from `text/plain` to `text/javascript` as describe in the [FAQ](https://www.pgadmin.org/faq/#12).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just adding/setting the environment variable `SERVER_MODE=True` it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, another option.
Tray icon, right click and select "new pgAdmin window..."
and in my case used Yandex.browser

Answer (score 0):

Comment this line of code out.  This is far less invasive than opening up a browser's security.  Since you are simply connecting locally, just comment out the tool's security.  pgAdmin is typically run from a client computer anyway, not from the machine where the database server resides.  So to do a smoke test, this is fine.

Search bar > type "explore.exe" (Windows Explorer) > run as administrator > open this file in a text editor > save file after commenting the line out.

C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/13/pgAdmin 4/venv/Lib/site-packages\werkzeug\exceptions.py

```
def __call__(self, code, *args, **kwargs):
    if not args and not kwargs and not isinstance(code, integer_types):
        raise HTTPException(response=code)
    if code not in self.mapping:
        raise LookupError("no exception for %r" % code)
    #raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs) # <-------- comment line 807 in exceptions.py
```

Right click Windows Task Bar > Task Manager > end process for "pgAdmin 4 Desktop Runtime".  This is the pgAdmin server for the pgAdmin 4 Desktop client.  This is different from the PostgreSQL server.  Then restart pgAdmin in Administrator mode.

Answer (score -5):

it's simple , just delete file pgadmin from C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4 , and C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin , delete the files , all of it , and install it again

Comment: Uninstalling all the software couldn't be consider as a solution.

Comment: you just have to re-install it once