# How to solve for: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED when GET data to React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nginx, axios, postgrest

I'm trying to get this API call to work using axios:

```
const getData = () => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3000/security?select=symbol,company",
    {headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer 73Ntx3b6SwNXC7ANV3tw4wFfDdKntB26',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                mode: "cors",               
    }}
    ).then((response) => {
        console.log(response)
    })
}
```

My local API server is up and running, I can make requests using `curl` and see JSON data. However, the calls do not work when I implement a `GET` request in my React App.

I'm a little curious to know why I'm getting these errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84)
createError @ createError.js:16
handleError @ xhr.js:84
```

Something is blocking the API from showing the data, I assume it's React. In my stack, this connection to `localhost:3000` API is only used once in the code above, it simply retrieves unique data...

Any ideas on how to solve?

EDIT: I have added a picture to show that the port is up and my API is up
[image]

EDIT EDIT:
So I tested my API live in production to see if it was a backend issue, I can access my API live from a real web-address. No issue there. I guess I tinkered my backend closer to getting the API request to work with React, because now I'm getting an `401 unauthorized Request` instead of my previous error.

Here is the config file for my nginx backend for my api url:

```
    location /data/ {
      default_type  application/json;
      proxy_hide_header Content-Location;
      add_header Content-Location  /data/$upstream_http_content_location;
      add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
      proxy_set_header  Connection "";
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        }
}
```

I have also added new code for my REACT get request above.

Comment: Is your React application on port 3000? Perhaps your API and React application is conflicting?

Comment: if connection is refused, the port isn't open. therefore the api isn't running you are trying to connect to.

Comment: To answer both of your questions, I switched the React port to a different number. The port must be open because I can write curl requests in my terminal from `localhost:3000`

Comment: @Dre are you sure there is something running on that port? what does the output of curl to the above URL say?

Comment: @r3wt, please see my edit in my OG post. I have added a picture to help understand the problem better.

Comment: do you use wifi for React calls?

Comment: Hey @GurgenSargsyan, I do not use wifi for React calls. I have a pretty standard `create react app` frontend.

Comment: Can you try with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: @GurgenSargsyan, that sadly did not work.

Comment: Did you bootstrap with CRA, might need to set a proxy:  https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/react-how-to-proxy-to-backend-server-5588a9e0347

Comment: @ContextCue I saw that link before, but I'm just curious why I didn't need to do that for my other RESTful API. I even set up a proxy through `package.json` file, however that didn't seem to help the issue.

Comment: Can you do -v in curl? I wonder if the headers got anything. Also, can you pipe curl output to json_pp or jq and see if they parse it properly?

Comment: Also, just a thought. Pretty print might be affecting it too. Maybe (at least) remove newline characters in the response?

Comment: I have added a new updated to my OG post.

Comment: Which port is your nginx running on? I'm guessing it's not 3000, since it's proxy passing it to localhost:3000 ?

Comment: @pandamakes it's proxy passing localhost:3000 to be served through my web-domain.

Comment: Perhaps you are listening only on 127.0.0.1 (IPv4 localhost) but the browser attempts to connect to ::1 (IPv6 localhost) or vice-versa? Try `http://127.0.0.1:3000` or `http://[::1]:3000` to see if either of these is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set Axios baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000' and add option `mode: "cors"`

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, let me get back to you and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Alright yo, well without knowing more about your setup, I have a basic example working with the proxy setup.

It is using

- axios
- CRA
- express backend

https://github.com/ed42311/apiReactExample

It is missing the authentication part.  I can keep building on it with some knowledge about how you setup the backend.

Feel free to use it as a talking point.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have updated my post with a new error.

Comment: ok, so now you are getting 401 unauthorized instead of what you are getting before, which just means you are unauthorized.  How are you building the backend.  How is your Authorization setup, express middleware?

Comment: I'm hosting my API  on an NGINX server, I have added the configurations for the API on my new edit.

Comment: I also do not have any express middleware set-up that I know of, unless there is a default in `create react app`

Comment: hm...  yeh that's cool.  Middleware would go in your server, but it sounds like you are using  https://postgrest.org/en/v7.0.0/

don't know much about that, but I would try a minimal python or nodejs server build to falsify that the problem is react/axios

Besides that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354551/pg4admin-401-unauthorized-error
https://www.reddit.com/r/PostgreSQL/comments/asrpal/pg4admin_401_unauthorized_error/

Or...  you might need to allow specific headers... just hypothesizing now...  :D

Comment: At this point I’m sure it’s a backend error from the API, I have added the new method that I use to GET the request at the top of my OG post. Would appreciate some verification, if that looks fine then it’s my backend issue.