# Unable to connect to server... connection time out in pgadmin

Tags: azure, psql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I installed Psql in azure virtual machine (linux) and Pgadmin-4 in windows VM. When I try to access Psql through Pgadmin getting connection time out error. I enabled all traffic between 2 VMs. when I checked the Pgadmin logs it shown 401 error

[image]

[image]

In  server manager I put off IE Enhanced security configuration.
modified postgresql-conf file listen address to * & pg_hba.conf with proper IPs

Comment: 401 error code means you are unauthorized, check your access details like the password (the default for Postgres is 'postgres')

Comment: all credentials are correct only

Answer (score 0):

Created SQL in azure Linux virtual machine and accessed in windows Pgadmin-4:

[image]

To enable remote configuration using pgadmin

Try to set password to access to Postgres user using below cmd:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
\password postgres
```

Now open the `psql` to connect the request, you can use this **`psql -U postgres -c 'SHOW config_file'`** to identify your config file.

```c
sudo vim  /etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf
sudo vim /etc/postgresql/12/main/pg_hba.conf
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
sudo systemctl status postgresql
```

[image]

Open the config file in connection and authentication click *insert* localhost with **`listen_addresses = '*'`** :

[image]

On `pg_hba.conf` file and add Ip address:

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host all all ::0/0 md5
```

[image]

Once you restart the PostgreSQL and it will give response with global 5432 and add port in virtual machine:

[image]

Now, when I check the connection its connected successfully like below:

```
psql -d postgres
\conninfo
```

[image]

If still issue persists, you can check this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354551/pg4admin-401-unauthorized-error) thread by *Leonard AB*